# Slurm array taking double cpus than requested

Tags: arrays, cpu, slurm

Im having some problems with Slurm arrays, because they take the double of CPUs than requested.

We have a node with 60 cores available for a Slurm queue, and when I launch a toy array example with 24 cpus, sinfo tells that they are being used 48 cpus. This is the toy example that I ran:

`sbatch --array=1-24 -N1 test_script.sh`

And this is the content of test_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=job.%J.out
#SBATCH --error=job.%J.err
#SBATCH --job-name="array_test"
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1

echo "My SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID: " $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

sleep 60
```

Strangely, when I check the cores that each user is taking with  `squeue -o "%.15i %.25j %.8u %.2t %.9P %C %.6D %R %.10M %e %l"` slurm counts only the requested cores for the user (24 in this case). But when I check how many cores are being used with sinfo `sinfo -p day -N -o "%.5a %.6t %N %C"` here I see that 48 cores are actually being used.

I have been playing with the sbatch options in the test script, like --cpus-per-task and --ntasks, but so far I haven't been able to solve the problem.

We are using Slurm 16.05.10-2 in a CentOS 7 machine.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you post the SelectType lines of your slurm.conf, and the section that shows nodes and partitions? It sounds like Slurm is allocating the number of full cores (24) but sinfo shows the number of threads (48).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the following settings in slurm.conf:

```
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
```

When you ask slurm for 1 CPU (which in Slurm means 1 thread), it allocates 1 core = 2 CPUs = 2 threads.
So your 24-job array will take 24 cores = 48 CPUs. You would get the same result allocating 2 CPUs per task.

Slurm can be configured to allocate based on CPUs (by setting SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU, removing the socket/core/thread information, and only leaving the CPU=thread count). See https://slurm.schedmd.com/cpu_management.html for more details.

From experience, it is difficult to then constrain jobs to only use the resources that they are allocated (and not all CPUs on the machine, for example), so after trying out CR_CPU, our group moved back to CR_CORE combined with enforcing ConstrainCores/ConstrainDevices using cgroup (see Slurm's [cgroup.conf documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroup.conf.html)).